# Injecting a pipe for usage in an exported function (not in component code) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a utility file with a bunch of methods that I export for usage in my components. Basically, something like this.

```
export function shazoo(amount: number) : string { ... }
```

On my components, I'm using a pipe for uniform formatting of the output to the screen. It looks like this.

```
@Pipe({ name: "format" })
export class FormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): string { ... }
}
```

It seems to be a wise idea to apply that specific pipification even inside the method, which was the case while it resided in the component (because it was injected in the constructor of it).

Then I had the bright idea of moving it to *utils.ts* for general purpose and now the injection doesn't work because the exported function doesn't reside in a class. It's imply imported into the using components.

What is the proper way to inject the pipe in this case? Is it injectable to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a separate `UtilityService` with `@Injectable()`, provide it in root. here you can use `FormatPipe` as dependency

You can copy all your utility methods here and use `FormatPipe` in that methods. 
now wherever you want to use utility methods, you can inject `UtilityService` in component and use it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution I'm leaning towards. The question targets to find out if it's the **only** proper way to do that or if it's possible to inject stuff otherwise as well. There are technical/practical considerations that make it a bit complicated to introduce the collecting class for the methods in out particular case.